# Winrt - Remove background color from pushpin on bing map

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have this map on a windows store app project.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Height="150" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Maps:Map Tag="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" Loaded="Map_Loaded" DataContext="{Binding}" ZoomLevel="10"  Margin="0,10,0,0"  DoubleTappedOverride="Map_DoubleTappedOverride" ShowBreadcrumb="False" Height="150" ShowNavigationBar="False"  ShowScaleBar="False" ShowTraffic="True" ShowBuildings="True" Width="350" Credentials="AnZKLHgAfKSwa5BAB2Kr-g8KENJBm1US3tVieyOCEwbJzCDUAgxhgJZVXyUgRIwM" ViewChanged="Map_ViewChanged" >
                            <Maps:Map.Children>
                                <Maps:Pushpin Tapped="Pushpin_Tapped" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                                    <Maps:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="3"/>
                                    </Maps:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
                                    <Maps:Pushpin.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Meetings/meetingsPushpin.png"/>
                                    </Maps:Pushpin.Background>

                                    <Maps:MapLayer.Position>
                                        <Maps:Location  Latitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" Longitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLng}" />
                                    </Maps:MapLayer.Position>
                                </Maps:Pushpin>
                            </Maps:Map.Children>
                        </Maps:Map>
                    </StackPanel>
```

And the pushpin image im using is this one that has a transparent background.

[image]

But when i run the app, the pushpins appears like this, with a white background.

[image]

How can i remove that white background, so i just have the blue pushpin?

Comment: I would strongly suggest converting that image to `Path` geometry data to make it a vector graphic instead of placing it as an image. If not just to make it look cleaner when scaling like that.

Comment: not sure how thats done eheh :D

Comment: Did you have a graphics person make the image? If so and they used like Adobe Illustrator then one easy way is just to use Mike Swanson's [AI to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) plugin that will do it for ya. I use it in AICS5 all the time. Plus you get the bonus of smooth scaling, no background, and only the Path area IsHitTestVisible=True, also makes it easy to add animations, color changes, etc real easily if you want to expand on the functionality in the future.

Answer (score -1):

try this, I´ve the XAML-Code for the graphic.

```
        <Viewbox>
        <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="Layer_1" Width="800" Height="600" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Ellipse Width="513.333" Height="513.333" Canvas.Left="157.083" Canvas.Top="40.5834" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="13.3333" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF006695"/>
            <Ellipse Width="125" Height="125" Canvas.Left="354.749" Canvas.Top="142" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF006695" Fill="#FF006695"/>
            <Path Width="21.1536" Height="21.393" Canvas.Left="377.778" Canvas.Top="166.895" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF006695" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 396.481,169.055C 400.219,172.614 399.612,179.321 395.124,184.036C 390.635,188.75 383.966,189.688 380.228,186.129C 376.489,182.57 377.097,175.863 381.585,171.148C 386.073,166.433 392.742,165.496 396.481,169.055 Z "/>
            <Path Width="16.05" Height="167" Canvas.Left="407.976" Canvas.Top="257" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="15" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF006695" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 416.526,264.5L 415.476,416.5L 416.526,264.5 Z "/>
            <Ellipse Width="68" Height="15" Canvas.Left="381.25" Canvas.Top="410.5" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF006695" Fill="#FF006695"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```

You can customize and optimize the code like you need it and create a custom pushpin. How to do that, you can find here at MSDN under "Adding a custom pushpin" -->  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709044.aspx

Comment: how would i apply that to my pushpin?

Comment: just replace the Imagebrush of the Maps:Pushpin.Background with the code. You can wrap the Canvas and its childs with a Viewbox for scaling the content. Path-objects have fixed sized, so if you don´t want to fix all the sizes, the viewbox will do the trick for you. 

I fixed the sample above

Comment: im getting these errors http://oi58.tinypic.com/k1cq5e.jpg  , here is my code http://paste2.org/3KvNeI9v

Comment: here you can find a "adding a custom pushpin"-section. Use the code and replace the stuff inside the canvas between the m:maps-tags with the content of the canvas/viewbox I send you above.